# MySql Workbench - difference between "Local instance 3306" and "Localhost via pipe"?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Im learning how to build a simple web app using PHP and MySQL. Tools:

-XAMPP for database, web and php servers
-Sublime for writing the code itself
-Mac OSX Yosemite
**- Workbench for database creation**

I'm having trouble understanding (and finding a good tutorial) how Workbench actually works. If I got things correctly, I need to create a connection between the Workbench (tool) and the database which sits "inside" the database server? In my case, provided by XAMPP.

After I get these two talking, I then create, edit, etc. tables inside this database, right?

Currently I have two MySql connections on the homescreen, please see attached file.[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically just the connection/transfer method. You can connect to a MySQL server via a `named pipe` if such ability is provided by the operating system OR via TCP connection which is generally for network access but also works and is widely used for localhost connections.

It is transparent to the user and should not affect the communication between server and the client. Those two will connect to the same database using different types of communication channels.

Answer (score 0):

"Local instance 3306" connects via TCP/IP on port 3306, while "Localhost via pipe" connects using a named pipe. Both methods access the MySQL database on your local machine, but TCP/IP is more common. Named pipes offer slightly better performance for local connections, especially on Windows.